# Git Flow, checked out branch from master, rebase to develop

Tags: git, github, rebase

Im working with `git flow` and I have a `master` and `develop` branch.
Sometimes people dont checkout from `master` but `develop`.
When the `PR` is submitted in `GitHub` it points to `master`.
Can I somehow change that the branch is based of of `develop`?

I found `git rebase` but dont exactly know if its what im searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is one of the things rebase can do for you. Assuming the incorrectly based branch is called `foo` and you want to change the base from `master` to `develop` (the direction you want wasn't entirely clear to me from your question), this is how to do it:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase --onto develop master
```

The manpage for `git rebase`  has a lot more details about how rebase works and what it does, as does the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

The most important thing to know here is that if `master` and `develop` are sufficiently different, the rebase operation might run into conflicts that you will have to fix manually - for every single commit on `foo` in the worst case. Rebase conflicts can be a little counter-intuitive, so don't rush through it. :)